# Packing files as jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to create a jar file off of a class and xml file I have in a directory called SOACustomFunction.

```
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise - 64 Bit
Java: jdk1.6.0_21
```

I tried using the command below and I keep getting the error:

```
Error: "Unable to access jarfile SOACustomFunction.jar"

C:\SOACustomFunction>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java.exe" -jar -cvf
SOACustomFunction.jar *.*
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

S

Comment: How are you creating the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you show is what you would use to EXECUTE the jar file.  Use `jar.exe` instead of `java.exe -jar`

Comment: Thanks Jim.....when you mentioned jar.exe I realized it was my call to java.exe and the -jar -cvf that were wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would have

```
jar cvf yourJarFile.jar yourClass.class yourSecondClass.class
```

`java -jar` is for running a class from a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your classes and xml reside inside your SOACustomFunction directory, the command would be

```
cd SOACustomFunction
jar cvf myjar.jar yourclass.class yourxml.xml
```

But do maintain a package structure for your classes and other resources instead of having them all in the jar's root directory.